# Disconnect link between copied charts in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-chart

I created a `Pivot Chart` in Excel and added a filter.
I would like to create copies of the chart with different filter selected in each one.
But it seems there is a link between them, and when I change the filter selection in one, they all update accordingly.

How do I create a copy if the chart without the linking between them.

Comment: If you, instead of copying the charts, add new ones, the link between them you are reporting does not exist. They are two independent pivot charts. I tested it on Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1):

When you have several pivot tables or pivot Charts, the data source is the same. When creating the 1st Pivot table the raw datas are imported into a "data cache".

You have to unshare this data cache in order to prevent interactions between two or more pivot objects. It's well described in the [MS Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Unshare-a-data-cache-between-PivotTable-reports-87188806-0c24-4d17-b2f7-9e3a4a05542b#bm2).
Be aware that your file size will be so bigger.